# category_list param for test page creation request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, request

Having created a test user for my app, I intend to create a test page by sending the following POST request to the Facebook API (some parts obviously replaced with dummies):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/<TEST_USER_ID>/accounts?access_token=<APP_TOKEN>&name=Dummypage&category_enum=BANK&about="Text"&picture=<URL_TO_IMAGE>&cover_photo={"url": "<URL_TO_OTHER_IMAGE>"}&location={"city": "SomeCity","state": "SomeState","country": "DE"}&address="<ADDRESS>"&phone="<PHONE>"&category_list=[{"id": "133576170041936"} ,{"id": "145988682478380"}]
```

The problematic part of this is the category_list parameter, which I have attempted to pass in many forms already. Arriving at

```
category_list=[{"id": "133576170041936"} ,{"id": "145988682478380"}]
```

I finally no longer get the error that the param has to be an array - instead I get the following error: `(#100) Param category_list[0] must be a valid ID string (e.g., \"123\")` .
This is fairly confusing, as the IDs are taken from the response of an API response containing the page categories:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/fb_page_categories?access_token=<TOKEN>
```

**How should the parameter be correctly passed?**

---

**What I tried so far:**

```
category_list=["145988682478380"]
category_list=[145988682478380]
```

Result: (#100) Invalid parameter

```
category_list=[{"id": "145988682478380"}]
category_list=[{"id": "145988682478380", "name": "Kreditgenossenschaft", "api_enum": "CREDIT_UNION"}]  #full entry as listed in page categories response
```

Result: (#100) Param category_list[0] must be a valid ID string (e.g., "123")

**Documentation references**
[Page category](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-category/)
[Creating a test page via POST request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages/)

Comment: They say they want just `"123"`, you are sending `{"id": "123"}` … So it should actually be `category_list=["133576170041936", "145988682478380"]`, from my understanding.

Comment: That was my first thought when seeing the response. However, passing that returns "(#100) Invalid parameter"

Comment: I think you need to pass only child category IDs in `category_list`? `133576170041936` is the ID of the parent category `BANK` itself, and that is specified via `category_enum` already.

Comment: That, sadly, also results in the above "invalid parameter" error. I'll add a collection of things I have tried later.

Answer (score 0):

This curl command worked by me:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"category_list\": [192803624072087, 145988682478380]}" "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me?access_token=[page_access_token]"
```

So with the following JSON Body:

```
{
  "category_list": [192803624072087, 145988682478380]
}
```